A batch file with an executable file checks if it is not in the processes in order to run another batch file (or code from it)
There are two batch files. Need to add a condition to the first file if the process is running nvcplui.exe then nothing, and if it is not running, then the second file (or the code from it) will be applied. I am far from programming, so I will be grateful for the finished version.
1 bat
sc config NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem start=auto

net start NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem

start "" "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIAControlPanel\nvcplui.exe"

2 bat
net stop NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem

sc config NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem start= disabled


Check if is it running or not,use sc query

Of the two bat files, I understand file 1 is to start the process, while file 2 is to disable it. So, what is your main goal?

To make everything works when running one batch file, Run 1 batch file, the exe start, I work in the application, close the application and 2 batch file were applied. Or that the same thing would work through a single batch file.

I don't know exactly what you mean.
This is just a script to run and close it. you can choose according to your wishes. (Admin right required).
@Echo Off
:NVidia
CLS 
set #name=NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem
sc query | Find.exe /i "%#name%" >Nul && set #Run=y || set #Run=
if defined #Run (
    Echo '%#name%' is Running. Close It^?
) else (
    Echo '%#name%' is Not Running. Start It^?
)
choice /n /m "(Y) Yes (N) Exit:"
if %errorlevel%==2 exit /b
if defined #Run goto :CloseIt

:RunIt
rem sc config NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem start=auto
net start NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem
start "" "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIAControlPanel\nvcplui.exe"
goto :NVidia

:CloseIt
net stop NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem
rem sc config NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem start= disabled
goto :NVidia

if it's just for running and closing, there's no need for sc config. That's its function is to start automatically at startup or deactivate it.
But if you want that, remove rem.
If you want to learn cmd, one easy-to-read reference is SS64

To just run it through the bat, pause, then close.
@Echo Off
rem sc config NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem start=auto
net start NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem
start "" "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIAControlPanel\nvcplui.exe"
pause
net stop NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem
rem sc config NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem start=disabled


If it's just to run it using bat and close it manually, that's easier. Is that what is meant?

Is there a technical possibility not to answer "yes" or "no", that is, without a choice inside the cmd shell. Provided, if we take as initial data, that service NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem is disabled by default. By launching the bat file, the service NV Display.Container Local System is enabled and starts nvcplui.exe -pause, then I close it manually nvcplui.exe . -resuming work after that, checking if nvcplui.exe  dont run, then NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem id shutdown and bat file shutdown to.

Sorry for the inaccurate queries, English is not my native language, I write through a translator.

Thanks a lot, this option is really almost what I wanted.
@Echo Off
sc config NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem start=auto
net start NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem
start "" "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIAControlPanel\nvcplui.exe"
pause
net stop NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem
sc config NVDisplay.ContainerLocalSystem start=disabled

